# Keyboard shortcut to switch b/t multiple MacVim instances (not tabs or split windows)

Tags: osx-lion, macvim

In SL one could hit F10 and see only the MacVim instances which made it easy to switch between *n* instances. Anyone know if this is possible in Lion?

Comment: Found it myself: Apple Key + ` (tilde)

Answer (score 6):

Found it myself: Apple Key + ` (tilde)